# how to give a function a parameter without executing it in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to execute a function with the module Threading and it has a parameter but every different call need every different parameter so how do I do.

I tried this code it's a simple one:

```
import threading
def printer(a):
    print(a)
x=threading.Thread(target=printer("hello"))
z=threading.Thread(target=printer("world"))
x.start()
z.start()
```

when giving that () into printer(a) it automatically calls the function not with threading module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give different names to ThreadPoolExecutor threads in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439283/how-to-give-different-names-to-threadpoolexecutor-threads-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call signature of threading.Thread is the following

```
threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)
```

We can see that it takes the keyword argumets args and kwargs this is were your arguments go.
So in your code you write:

```
x = threading.Thread(target=printer, args=('hello',))
```