# Writing to file in specific format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method which generates and returns a string and a list of strings. Example:

```
def func():
    string_val = some code to generate string...
    list_of_string = some code to generate list of string...
    return string_val, list_of_string
```

Output:

```
string_val = 'some string_1'
list_of_string = ['string 1.1', 'string 1.2']
```

My method will be called by multiple threads (I am using `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures.thread`) and each thread will generate different data.

I want to write this data to a file in below format:

```
some string_1   <-- value returned by thread 1
some string_2   <-- value returned by thread 2
.
.
.
some string_n   <-- value returned by thread n

string 1.1   <-- value returned by thread 1
string 1.2   <-- value returned by thread 1
string 2.1   <-- value returned by thread 2
string 2.2   <-- value returned by thread 2
string 2.3   <-- value returned by thread 2
.
.
.
string n.m   <-- value returned by thread n
```

**Edit:**

The value generated and stored in `list_of_string` depends on value of `string_val`.

Is there an optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: I can write ```string_val``` to separate file and ```list_of_string ``` to separate file and merge those files later, but I want a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `thread_name_prefix` in order to assign a specific name for each thread pool.

You can have a look at this question and example

[How to give different names to ThreadPoolExecutor threads in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439283/how-to-give-different-names-to-threadpoolexecutor-threads-in-python)